# What's the correct way to find all entities ordered by field in Spring Data?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I'm using Spring Data JPA and want to add a method in my base Repository interface to get all entities ordered by field `order`:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface OrderedEntityDao<T extends OrderedEntity> extends EntityDao<T, Long> {
    List<T> findOrderByOrder();
}
```

`OrderedEntity` is a `@MappedSuperclass` entity.

But I'm getting exception when creating this bean:

```
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:854)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterMetadataProvider.next(ParameterMetadataProvider.java:121)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator$PredicateBuilder.build(JpaQueryCreator.java:274)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.toPredicate(JpaQueryCreator.java:180)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.create(JpaQueryCreator.java:109)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.create(JpaQueryCreator.java:49)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createCriteria(AbstractQueryCreator.java:109)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:88)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:73)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$QueryPreparer.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:118)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$CountQueryPreparer.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:241)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:68)
```

How to write this method correct?

**Edit:**

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class OrderedEntity extends IdEntity implements Comparable<OrderedEntity> {
    @Nonnull
    @Column(name = "`order`")
    private Long order;
}
```

Comment: Please add your OrderedEntity.java class here..

Comment: @ParthSolanki, here you are

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct named query will be:

```
public interface OrderedEntityDao<T extends OrderedEntity> extends EntityDao<T> {

    public List<T> findAllByOrderBy<colname><Desc|Asc>();

}
```

In your case:

```
public List<T> findAllByOrderByOrderDesc();
public List<T> findAllByOrderByOrderAsc();
```

Comment: Great! This works!

findAll_By_OrderBy<colname>
I missed this **By** predicate with no field after it.

Comment: Please mark it as an answer by clicking on gray tick below te score.

Comment: @omickron [Example 2.12](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html#jpa.query-methods.named-queries)

Answer (score 3):

I think this below code is work,

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface OrderedEntityDao<T extends OrderedEntity> extends EntityDao<T, Long> {
    List<T> findAllOrderByOrderAsc();
}
```

Comment: This one looks definitely better than @xenteros' answer. He has one "By" too much.

Comment: @DidierL, findAllOrderByOrderAsc throws the same exception.

Comment: @DidierL the difference is that my code works, and Parth's code doesn't.

Comment: @xenteros I see, my bad. I thought the (first) `By` could be omitted when there was no search criteria, but apparently not. In fact, we can even see in [Limiting query results](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result) that they are using the same "pattern" in their examples. And the "All" here does not affect the name parsing, so this is basically the same code as in the question. I think this answer should be removed then.

Answer (score -1):

It should be

```
public List<T> findByOrder(Long order);
```

The correct syntax for query methods with Spring Data is basically `findBy` followed by the variable names, separated with `And`/`Or`. Refer to the full documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods).

Comment: But I don't want to find by Order field. I want to find all entities, but *sorted by* order.

Comment: My bad, misread your question. In this case: `findAllByOrderAsc()`/`findAllByOrderDesc()`.